# I am getting WARNING:tensorflow:From in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am learning ML from AI Adventures but I have a problem with that code

> `WARNING:tensorflow:From Ai1.py:12: load_csv_with_header (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   Use tf.data instead.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "Ai1.py", line 12, in <module>
>       target_dtype=np.int)
>     File "C:\Users\Ardit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Ardit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\base.py", line 53, in load_csv_with_header
>       header = next(data_file)
>     File "C:\Users\Ardit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 220, in __next__
>       return self.next()
>     File "C:\Users\Ardit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 214, in next
>       retval = self.readline()
>     File "C:\Users\Ardit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 184, in readline
>       return self._prepare_value(self._read_buf.ReadLineAsString())
>     File "C:\Users\Ardit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 100, in _prepare_value
>       return compat.as_str_any(val)
>     File "C:\Users\Ardit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py", line 107, in as_str_any
>       return as_str(value)
>     File "C:\Users\Ardit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py", line 80, in as_text
>       return bytes_or_text.decode(encoding)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 8: invalid start byte`

I am using python 3.6
Can anyone help me

Comment: You are not showing any code, only the warning

Comment: Its all there in the warning. " load_csv_with_header" is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, here is the code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets import base

# Data files
IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"

# Load datasets.
training_set = base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
                                     features_dtype=np.float32,
                                     target_dtype=np.int)
test_set = base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TEST,
                                features_dtype=np.float32,
                               target_dtype=np.int)

print(training_set.data)

print(training_set.target)
```

Comment: you should edit your question and add the code to it.